# Single click in Gedit file browser to open files & folders

Tags: gedit

How do I open files & folders in the file browser with a **single click** in gedit?

Like how it is in text editors (Sublime, Atom, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The file browser in Gedit on a normal Ubuntu distribution is simply an extension of the Nautilus file manager.  If you want the files to open with a single click, you will have to enable single click opening in the Nautilus file manager.

Go to any folder and select from the Menus `Edit > Preferences`.  Then under the `Behaviour` tab, select the `Single Click to open items` radio button.

The downside is that this is the way your whole operating system will work from there on.  However, this will enable single click opening in the gedit side panel.

Comment: I'm actually on elementary OS which has single clicking on its file manager by default; but the single clicking does not carry over to gedit. I will have to research more on it. Thanks!

Comment: @puerile, is nautilus installed?

Comment: @anyonymous2 yes it is.

Comment: @peurile try changing the settings in Nautilus anyhow, then.  It worked on my system.